# How to specify "valid until" date in OpenVpn for a user?

Tags: openvpn, vpn

When I generate a certificate of OpenVpn for a user, is there any way to specify the "valid until" date? So that once that valid date has passed, a user is no longer able to connect to an OpenVpn server, a server will reject it.